# Navigation isn't picking up CSS

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I've been trying to make a drop down CSS menu all night and for some reason, no matter how I mess with the coding, my navigation tags are not picking up the CSS.

Here is the site: http://nellyswritingroom.tumblr.com/

The CSS:

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;  }
#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0; }
#nav li {
    float: left; }
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #fff; }
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{text:Nav Link 1}">{text:Link 1 Name}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{text:Nav Link 2}">{text:Link 2 Name}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{text:Nav Link 3}">{text:Link 3 Name}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{text:Nav Link 4}">{text:Link 4 Name}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{text:Nav Link 5}">{text:Link 5 Name}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{text:Nav Link 6}">{text:Link 6 Name}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried several different methods to setting up the navigation, such as using the html nav tags and styling... but it's not changing anything. The CSS is not reaching the HTML for some reason, which is odd, because the CSS is working fine for the rest of the page.

I'm sure this is something that I'm overlooking, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: its taking css http://jsfiddle.net/Pzp5a/

Comment: Right, but on the actual website, the CSS doesn't take.

Comment: in the actual website you have used <nav> in html and in the provided css you have used #nav

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out... fixed it, but the issue persists.

Comment: check the Sowmya jsFiddle link its working fine

Comment: I think in the actual website you haven't write any css for #nav, please check your css again.

Comment: may be then there is some issue with Tumblr. your html code and css style works fine in my local system as well as jsFiddle.

Comment: I checked again... made sure my external CSS was linked & it is. It's here: onedirectionconnection.com/newstyle.css .

Comment: Well, thanks for your help anyway. It must be something with Tumblr, like you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your issue in 'newstyle.css'

```
header#top h1{
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:285px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
)
```

closing tag ')' should be '}'

Comment: Oh my gosh... Wow. That was it. Thank you SOO MUCH.